# Populate data from mysql to ListView (JQuery Mobile) using ajax

Tags: ajax, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

```
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="responsecontainer" >
  </ul>
```

This is my html file.

```
var output = $('#responsecontainer');   
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.1.28/mobile/db_select.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
            var landmark = '<li><a href="#"><h2>'+item.tr_issue+'</h2>'
            + '<p>'+item.tr_assign+'</p></a></li>';
            output.html(landmark);
            console.log(output);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
```

This is my JavaScript.

I want to populate my listview from my database(mysql) but the problem is when it generates the theme of jquery mobile di not work.

[image]

its like a simple unordered list. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$('ul').listview('refresh');` after appending the HTML

Show change your success callback as below

```
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
            var landmark = '<li><a href="#"><h2>'+item.tr_issue+'</h2>'
            + '<p>'+item.tr_assign+'</p></a></li>';
            output.html(landmark);
            console.log(output);
        });
         $('ul').listview('refresh');
    },
```